# How can I validat each character entered by the user in MFC property grid control (CMFCPropertyGridCtrl)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have been trying to validate and update each character in the properties edit box (`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`) which was entered by the user.I searched the MSDN and find function like `PushChar()` etc. But those methods didn't solve my problem. Basically I need to implement `CEdit::OnChar()` function  for the `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` edit boxes.
[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to override PreTranslateMessage and process the messages for WM_CHAR there? According to the documentation it supports the PTM method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983759.aspx

Comment: `CEdit::OnChar()` is not what you're looking for, nor is its `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` equivalent. Both would fail to account for input coming from sources other than the keyboard (e.g. a mouse paste operation). You need to respond to change notifications.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think you can't do it via OnChar, even when it comes from keyboard, because it is being overridden by its own `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::PreTranslateMessage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to give the sample code for this. In `CustomProperties.h`, Derive a class form **`CMFCPropertyGridProperty`**

```
class CMyEditProp : public CMFCPropertyGridProperty
{
public:
    CMyEditProp (const CString& strName, const CString& strValue, LPCTSTR lpszDescr = NULL, DWORD dwData = 0);

protected:
    virtual CWnd* CreateInPlaceEdit(CRect rectEdit, BOOL& bDefaultFormat);
    virtual CString FormatProperty();
};
```

Also derive a class from **`CEdit`** and implement a **`OnChar()`** method in it.

```
class MyEdit:public CEdit
{
public: 
        void OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
        {
          if(!IsCharAlpha(nChar))
            return;

          CEdit::OnChar(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
        }
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

In `CustomProperties.cpp` Implement all the methods which were declared in header file.

```
CMyEditProp ::CPasswordProp(const CString& strName, const CString& strValue, LPCTSTR lpszDescr, DWORD dwData)
: CMFCPropertyGridProperty(strName, (LPCTSTR) strValue, lpszDescr, dwData)
{
}

CWnd* CMyEditProp ::CreateInPlaceEdit(CRect rectEdit, BOOL& bDefaultFormat)
{
    MyEdit pWndEdit;
    DWORD dwStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL ;

    if (!m_bEnabled || !m_bAllowEdit)
    {
        dwStyle |= ES_READONLY;
    }

    pWndEdit.Create(dwStyle, rectEdit, m_pWndList, AFX_PROPLIST_ID_INPLACE);


    bDefaultFormat = TRUE;
    return &pWndEdit;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyEdit,CEdit)
    ON_WM_CHAR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This will work like as Edit control and you can validate all the characters entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

When you provide `lpszEditMask` or `lpszEditTemplate` or `lpszValidChars` parameters to the constructor of a property, the edit control of that property will be a `CMFCMaskedEdit` instead of a normal `CEdit`. You can confirm what I said on `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit` implementation.

So, if I was in your place, I would read `CMFCMaskedEdit` documentation to know how to input the masking, put a breakpoint on `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit` to see how it behaves when you supply the `lpsz...` arguments and then would come back here to the page to report how had things gone.

Comment: CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit is working fine for me

Comment: `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::CreateInPlaceEdit` is a virtual function. Did you override it on a derived class made by you?